# I killed Sinding and got his skin. Is there anyway I can get the Ring Of Hircine again?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I did the quest to get the ring of Hircine but I thought I was meant to kill Sinding. Now I have completed the quest and only have his skin. Is there any way that I can re-do the quest or go on another quest to get the ring again?

Answer (score 3):

No, all quest rewards are final. However, you can use the console to give yourself the ring, if you're playing on PC. The code is `player.additem 2ac60 1`

Answer (score 2):

Nope, not without using console.  However, if you have an old save-file, it is possible to get *both* daedric artifacts available in that mission - you help Sinding out, get the reward, then go back and kill him.

Answer (score 1):

For your question, If you got the skin *first*, you can't get the ring afterwards.

However, there are some instances where you can exploit a glitch to get [more than what was intended](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/173622/73976).

If you (somehow) are able to load an old save *before* the start of the mission, you can get the ring *first*, then at the end of the mission, you can get the skin (from my previous answer):

> Sometimes, the game glitches out and upon completion of the quest (when trying for the ring) Sinding will reappear in the cell you first found him, in werewolf form. Killing him will relent the Savior's Hide. (this is tricky through the bars of the cell, but with timing and a save beforehand, you should prevail)

Answer (score 0):

If you load a save you should be able to redo the mission however you will lose some progress.

I've done this previously and it worked.

Answer (score -2):

YES THERE IS A WAY! Skip to 6:25

Comment: If you write up the information at 6:25-9:00 and add it to your answer, it will be a lot more useful to future visitors (and as an added bonus, is more likely to receive upvotes). It is much easier for someone to spend a few seconds reading the answer compared to watching a few minutes of a YouTube video. Furthermore, your answer risks becoming useless if that Youtube link ever goes bad.