# How many daedric missions are there that give you armor as a reward?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How many daedric missions are there that give you armor as a reward. I've only gone through a few of them and was wondering what the others were like and if they're worth possibly getting arrested.

Comment: In theory there should be 17, one for each Prince however i am unaware if they all are present in Skyrim (Except Jyggalag and Mehrunes Dagon i'm quite sure they all had a shrines in Oblivion). as far as i know Azura, Clavicus Vile, Nocturnal, Mehrunes Dagon, Namira and Meridia have shrines and there's 2 who i know you meet and do a mission with, Sanguine and Sheogorath, i'm unsure if either one have a shrine (just read about them).

Comment: as for which ones give you Armour i have no idea, i know Azura you have the option of Azura's Star + another follower or the Black Star (you can only get one or the other without console cheats) and Sheogorath gives you Wabbajack which is a weapon. i also wouldn't suspect any would get you something that you would be arrested for but i haven't done them all to fully know

Comment: my favorites sheogorath he reminds me of the mad hatter and thx for the answers

Comment: oh a little side question can you actually join potema the wolf queen i just got there and it kinda sounds like you can but im not sure

Comment: No, the quest requires you to destroy her. :(

Comment: @kotekzot No, I don't think so, the OP is just asking which ones give armour. That question was asking for the locations of each quest.

Comment: does any1 know where exactly the missions start cus i know one started with a random find a dog that turned out to be a talking dog that was also the pet of a deadra so they can be kinda random

Comment: Well that is where @kotekzot's reply will come in handy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 16 that give rewards, however one (part of the Thieve's guild questline) requires you to give it *back* to complete the quest (skeleton key)

There are 3 missions that give you non-equippable artefacts, 3 that give you staves, 5 that relinquish melee weapons, 4 that give you armour (and shields) and 2 that give you rings. (one mission can give you a ring or a chest piece, but I'll elaborate)

If you do them right, you can avoid getting arrested for all of them, and possibly even get more items than you are technically allowed (by way of glitches)

For example, in "Ill Met By Moonlight" you have a choice for a reward: the Ring of Hircine or the Savior's Hide. However, sometimes, the game glitches out and upon completion of the quest (when trying for the ring) Sinding will reappear in the cell you first found him, in werewolf form. Killing him will relent the Savior's Hide. (this is tricky through the bars of the cell, but with timing and a save beforehand, you should prevail)

On the other hand, the Oghma Infinium has it's own glitch that will allow you to level up indiefinitely by use of a bookshelf. [Here](http://youtu.be/0xotonVEDf4) is a quick guide on how to go about it. (This may have been patched).

For the remainder, I believe that all of the Daedric artifacts are quite OP, my favourite listing as the Dawnbreaker (Burns Undead, and causes explosions on death that causes undead to flee), Mehrune's Razor (has a small chance for an insta-kill, which works on ALL ENEMIES), and all of the rings are quite good as well. I personally prefer the Ring of Hircine, as I enjoy playing as a werewolf.

So to round up, yes. They are worth it.

Comment: dang thats alot i cant wait to find em all i think ive got 10 to go ive got a while to go i tend to get destracted by the random side quests and im lvl 30 and still havent gotin to greybeards

Comment: @Memor-X He doesn't make an appearance in Skyrim

Comment: Daedric Artifacts are not that op in my opinion ... escpecially the mask of clavicus vile, volendrung (the hammer of molag bal) and this staff of vermina are pretty weak. But yes, dawnbreaker is broken, true, especially for the dawnguard campaign. :D

Comment: @YUNOWORK Yeah I would agree with you there. And the only reason I enjoy Mehrune's Razor so much is because it doesn't have the drain on it's effect like all the other weapons

Comment: no one told me this before thankyou

Comment: @Ben And it looks badass. :3

Comment: The Oghma Infinium glitch was patched, at least on PC. 1.9.26.0.8 is the game version where the fix occurs, so if you haven't updated skyrim for some reason, it could still work.

Comment: I believe Oghma Infinium glitch was patched on xbox 360 as well.